# Disable proxy server for one apt repository

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

I have made a local apt repository, but my IT-department caches LAN traffic on the proxy server. Is there a way I could work around this to disable the proxy settings for this local apt repository? in apt.conf or simular?

Answer (score 26):

Just declare in a `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99proxy` file something like this :

```
Acquire::http::Proxy {
    your.local.first.repository DIRECT;
    your.second.first.repository DIRECT;
};
```

`DIRECT` tells apt to use a direct connection to connect to the repository.

Answer (score 7):

This is just [@Cédric Julien](https://askubuntu.com/users/18196/c%C3%A9dric-julien)'s answer with (thanks and) the additional syntax for defaulting to an external proxy:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy:8080";
Acquire::http::Proxy {
    in-house.debian.example.com DIRECT;
    no-protocol-colon-or-slashes.example.com DIRECT;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How again a 11 year old post, nevertheless i found it and one of the features of my code at

https://github.com/hastmu/apt-proxy-detect

is actually to skip non working proxies for some repositories, e.g. local ones.

Enjoy.

snipped of the detect process for local repos (blocked ones)

```
[        INFO][   1]: ===--- apt-proxy-detect ---===
[    TEST-URL][  16]: URL:  http://local-repo.fritz.box/local-repo/dists/trunk/InRelease
[        HASH][  24]: HASH: 2bfbb1335aaf9d333a5c9498226eb208 of (http://local-repo.fritz.box)
[       CACHE][  29]: using stored under: /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles/.apt-proxy-detect._apt
[       CHECK][  31]: once working proxy: http://192.168.0.27:8000 for http://local-repo.fritz.box/local-repo/dists/trunk/InRelease
# once working proxy failed
[ CHECK-PROXY][  41]: Proxy (http://192.168.0.27:8000) failed with testurl (http://local-repo.fritz.box/local-repo/dists/trunk/InRelease)
# search again
[       AVAHI][  46]: get cache entries for _apt_proxy._tcp
[       CHECK][  91]: Checking found proxy (http://192.168.0.27:8000) with testurl (http://local-repo.fritz.box/local-repo/dists/trunk/InRelease)
[ CHECK-PROXY][ 101]: Proxy (http://192.168.0.27:8000) failed with testurl (http://local-repo.fritz.box/local-repo/dists/trunk/InRelease)
Service[ER][Squid deb proxy on squid-deb-proxy]@http://192.168.0.27:8000 
[       CHECK][ 124]: Checking found proxy (http://192.168.0.27:3142) with testurl (http://local-repo.fritz.box/local-repo/dists/trunk/InRelease)
[ CHECK-PROXY][ 134]: Proxy (http://192.168.0.27:3142) failed with testurl (http://local-repo.fritz.box/local-repo/dists/trunk/InRelease)
Service[ER][apt-cacher-ng proxy on squid-deb-proxy]@http://192.168.0.27:3142 
# none found (as local repos are not allowed on the proxies)
[       PROXY][ 149]: return ::
[       CACHE][ 152]: Store (NONE) in cache file (/var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles/.apt-proxy-detect._apt)
[       CACHE][ 154]: Update cachefile.
[        INFO][   2]: ===--- apt-proxy-detect ---===
```